# Animal size database query

Tags: data-request, database, animals

I am looking for different database that would present length, height, weight etc.... Of an animal (any). I am looking for a table of at least 300 - 500 animals of one type in a table. Preferably mammals, but birds are good as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what kind of animals. I have the suspicion that if someone pointed you to a bird database, that would not be good enough. You could also replace the ambiguous term *observations*

Comment: Have you tried wikidata.org?

Comment: A similar question was asked at [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_about_public_databases_of_animals_body_size)  and got a number of answers.